# javascript code for converting distinguished name into canonical name

Tags: javascript, active-directory

This is distinguished name:

```
"CN=Peterson\,Misha,OU=Users,OU=Bright,OU=APAC,DC=xyz,DC=ang,DC=com".
```

I need to convert this into

```
"xyz.ang.com/APAC/Bright/Users/Peterson,Misha"
```

i.e., Canonical name.

1. Whatever comes in "DC" part is joined using "." i.e., "xyz.ang.com"
2. whatever comes in "OU" part comes after. with '/' in between.
3. And at last comes the "CN" part i.e., "Peterson,Misha".

Below javascript code produce "Peterson/" as output.

```
private static string ExtractCN(string dn)
{
    string[] parts = dn.Split(new char[] { ',' });

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        var p = parts[i];
        var elems = p.Split(new char[] { '=' });
        var t = elems[0].Trim().ToUpper();
        var v = elems[1].Trim();
        if (t == "CN")
        {
            return v;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want "xyz.ang.com/APAC/Bright/Users/Peterson,Misha" as output.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stackoverflow. We are not wizards therefore, cannot guess what is it you have tried (and provide a code sample of your attempt(s)) or failed to understand. I strongly suggest that you read the guide [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: You,ve figure out that you have a problem by splitting from `,` because the name has it too?

Comment: yes, i have splitted by ',' . What could possibly be other solution?

Comment: Can you clarify the language you're using? You say JavaScript, but that code isn't JavaScript. I assumed C# in my answer.

Comment: code inside the loop is javascript.

Comment: No, it really isn't JavaScript.

Comment: can you send complete code for the splitting one?thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to replace `\,` with some string that is guaranteed to not appear anywhere else in the string. That way, it is ignored when you `Split(",")`.

Then replace it with `,` when you return the result. In this case I use `"{comma}"`:

```
private static string ExtractCN(string dn)
{
    dn = dn.Replace("\\,", "{comma}");
    string[] parts = dn.Split(new char[] { ',' });

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        var p = parts[i];
        var elems = p.Split(new char[] { '=' });
        var t = elems[0].Trim().ToUpper();
        var v = elems[1].Trim();
        if (t == "CN")
        {
            return v.Replace("{comma}", ",");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

That answers your immediate question, but you still have some work to do since this only returns `"Peterson,Misha"`, not the full canonical name.

You could theoretically get better performance by not using `Split` and walking each character in the string yourself... but I doubt it would make a noticeable difference.

Your code example looks more like C# than JavaScript. If you are indeed using C#, you could just pull the value of the [`canonicalName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-canonicalname) attribute directly from Active Directory:

```
var de = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{dn}");
de.RefreshCache(new [] { "canonicalName" });
var canonicalName = (string) de.Properties["canonicalName"].Value;
```

Comment: please provide complete code for the splitting one.